# ¿Por qué un "pedal" es una borrachera?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, coloquialismos, españa

Hay decenas de sinónimos para borrachera, pero hoy quería preguntar sobre *pedal*.

Estaba hablando sobre un pedal que llevan algunos contenedores de basuras para abrir la tapa y he pensado que un pedal también era una borrachera y no se me ocurre una razón que relacione esos dos conceptos.

Un ejemplo de uso:

> Menudo pedal lleva ese, va haciendo eses por la calle.

¿De dónde viene llamar pedal a una borrachera?

Comment: Pues aparece actualmente como 2.ª acepción [en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SHtVuw8) pero el mapa de diccionarios nos hace ver que en 2001 ni siquiera aparecía allí.

Comment: Pues en mi entorno no ha aparecido todavía. Nunca la había oído. Creo que necesitamos una etiqueta de región porque por aquí no se usa.

Comment: ¿Es posible que solo se use en España? No tengo ni idea

Comment: Como dice @FGSUZ en su respuesta, puede ser una deformación de *pedo*, que significa borrachera en más de un dialecto.

Comment: Hay un par de referencias que avalan la teoría de que es una deformación de _pedo_: https://sinfaltas.com/2016/04/28/paganini-clarinete-y-otros-homonimos-parasitarios/: _A partir del uso de pedo para ‘borrachera’ (cuyo uso se justifica en algún sitio por el tufo que despiden los borrachos), se forma pedal,_ y http://forums.tomisimo.org/archive/index.php/t-1251.html _If you use pedal instead of pedo you're softening the phrase._

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Estoy casi seguro que es una deformación de la palabra "pedo", ya que "ir pedo" o "llevar un pedo" es  también una expresión para "ir borracho".

En cuanto a ir pedo, según los resultados de Google parece que se debe "al mal olor que los borrachos desprenden".

Así que me inclino por decir que es una mala utilización de un aumentativo de pedo, como "vaya pedaco" o algo similar.

Comment: Curiosa teoría, nunca se me hubiera ocurrido que pedo derivase en pedal. De momento parece la única explicación.

Comment: Quizá el uso de pedo para los borrachos provenga del estado de estupefacción de los mismos. ¿Exponerse a gas metano no genera que uno pierda el control de sus sentidos fisiológicos?

Comment: @blonfu, pues hay una tésis que avala esa idea y le dedominan homonimia parasitaria: "la homonimia parasitaria consiste en la modificación de un término para que adopte el significante de otro con el que tan solo comparte la estructura fonética inicial (generalmente las dos primeras sílabas, aunque, como mínimo, los dos sonidos iniciales)" [https://repositorio.uam.es/bitstream/handle/10486/671499/varela_villafranca_diego.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y].

Comment: @MauricioMartinez Interesante, le echaré un vistazo aunque es larguísimo el documento

Comment: allí se cita otro trabajo con algo interesante: – Calles y Bermejo (2001: 82) ya observan que de pedo ‘borrachera’ surge pedal por derivación fonética, indicando que «no tiene ninguna relación con la biela de las bicicletas»

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina se dice, estar en pedo, cuando una persona está bajo los efectos del alcohol. Y claro Pedal suena a pedo, acá en mi ciudad se hacen muchos juegos de palabras similares por ejemplo. En vez de decir - ¡Hola, ¿Todo bien?!, y que respondan - sí, Todo bien. se hace una frase como esta: ¡Hola, ¿Todo naranja?!, - Sí toronja. Cómo son palabras que se asemejan las usan como eufemismos, o como reemplazantes.

Sé también que en México se usa mucho "pedo", a secas, o "peda". Pero si me preguntás de dónde puede provenir el usar la palabra pedo para los beodos, ahí me mataste.